# I want to get elements from array in order: three, four, three, four and so on

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I want to get elements from an array like this: get first three element, then four elements, then again three elements, and again four, and so on in a loop.

For example:

```
0 1 2 

3 4 5 6

7 8 9

10 11 12 13

and so on....
```

I tried something like this:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    if($key <= 2) {
      echo 'test';
    }

    if($key > 2 && $key < 6) {
      echo 'other test';                            
    }

    if($key > 6 && $key < 9) {
      echo 'test';                            
    }  
}
```

However, I don't want to use `if()` like these, because I don't know how many items will be in the array: it comes from a database.

I think, I need something like `array_chunk($items, 3)` but for size parameter I need 3 and 4 in loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: 1. Show us at least a sample of the real array you are processing please

Comment: 2. Also some sort of code that you have written to attempt to do this for yourself

Comment: `foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    if($key <= 2) {
      echo 'test';
    }
                
    if($key > 2 && $key < 6) {
      echo 'other test';                            
    }
    
    if($key > 6 && $key < 9) {
      echo 'test';                            
    }  
}`

sorry for this code it's difficult to read code like this.
I tried something like this, but i don't want to write if statements like these, because, i don't know how many item will come from database

Answer (score 0):

Could be like this you can make another array of specifying the number of elements you want in each iteration.

```
<?php

$number_of_elements = [3,4,3,4];

$your_array = ['a', 'b','c','d','e'];

foreach($number_of_elements as $number){

for($i = 0; $i<=$number; $i++){

    $result = $your_array[$i];
    print_r($result);
} 

print_r('<br>');

}
```

Comment: this is a result of your code: 
`abcd  - 
abcde  -  
abcd  -  
abcde`

I want to be like these:

`abc - 
defg - 
hij -
klmn`

Comment: Change this array. 
$number_of_elements = [2,3,2,3];

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript you can solve your problem using a for loop and the built in slice function of the array.

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
let offset = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < array.length;){
  offset = offset === 3 ? 4 : 3;
  const subArray = array.slice(i, i + offset);
  console.log(subArray);
  i += offset;
}
```

Comment: he used php tag. guess he's using php then

Comment: You are right. the same logic will still work in php though.